# i need to add number after babyname when i run the script like that (babyname1 , babyname2 , Infinite)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# best baby name.

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
r = requests.get("https://family.disney.com/articles/1000-most-popular-boy-names/")

# check the website working or not.
print("Welcome. i think you have a new baby and you need a good name :D")
start = input("i'll upload a file text with a names in your computer agree Y/N :").strip().capitalize()
if r.status_code ==200 and start == "Y":
    print("*********************************************")
    #sleep(5)
else:
    print("there a problem in the server or you should type y.")
    exit()

# now the scrape baby <3 #

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
for list_ol in soup.find_all("ol"):
    print(list_ol.get_text().strip())
#ask the guy wanna save or not?#
ask_save = input("hey you wanna save it? Y/N : ").strip().capitalize()
if ask_save =="Y":

# fix this error FileExistsError:
    
    f = open("babynames.txt","x")
    f.write(list_ol.get_text().strip())
    if FileExistsError == True:
```

here when i get FileExistsError i need to make the script automation renamet this to babyname1
and after that to babyname2 and bla bla bla sorry my english it's bad.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.path.isfile` to see if you already have a file with that name before writing.

```
import os

i = 1
while os.path.isfile(f'babynames{i}.txt'):
    i += 1

f = open(f'babynames{i}.txt', "x")
f.write(list_ol.get_text().strip())
```

This will check babynames1.txt, then babynames2.txt, etc until it finds a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Just updated the code, should have been `while blah blah`, rather than `while not blah blah`. Otherwise it would have found that first file that DID exist.